# Regular Expression to add a character in front of the third occurrence of an uppercase letter

Tags: regex

How is it possible to add e.g. a dash `-` before the third uppercase letter in a string?

Example: `SuisseIntlBlack.woff2` should be `SuisseIntl-Black.woff2`

Answer (score 0):

### Regular Expression

By using the following regular expression it's possible to add any character in front of the third uppercase letter.

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)([A-Z]{1}[a-z].*)
```

My attempt was

1. to search for the first two groups beginning with one uppercase letter followed by the group of lowercase letters.
2. The third group begins with the exact same pattern
3. ... and adds also the rest of the string until the end.

The mentioned regular expression is live documented at https://regex101.com/r/BJMykV/1

### Replacement Snippet

The following snippet is used to add a dash between the second and third group of matches elements:

```
$1$2-$3
```

Comment: You can omit `{1}` from the pattern.